# Android TextView_Instance.setText() error

Tags: android, textview

I am having error that "mTvCreate can not be resoved" while setting up

```
mTvCreate.setText("onCreate() calls: " + mCreate);
```

this is one of the last four statements with same error in code given below

Also please can anyone explain

1. why in statement on line 1 to 4 of code below we define RESTART_KEY as string and assign it as "restart" what is the function of it.
2. what this statement "savedInstanceState.putInt(CREATE_KEY, mCreate);" in 
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) method will do. is this method only called to save state information when app is going to leave present activity and enter into another activity.

Thanks.

```
private static final String RESTART_KEY = "restart";
    private static final String RESUME_KEY = "resume";
    private static final String START_KEY = "start";
    private static final String CREATE_KEY = "create";

int mCreate, mRestart, mStart, mResume;

    TextView mTvCreate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create);
    TextView mTvRestart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restart);
    TextView mTvStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start);
    TextView mTvResume = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resume);

if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            // TODO:
            // Restore value of counters from saved state
            // Only need 4 lines of code, one for every count variable
            //savedInstanceState.getInt("mCreate", mCreate);
            //savedInstanceState.getInt("mRestart", mRestart);
            //savedInstanceState.getInt("mStart", mStart);
            //savedInstanceState.getInt("mResume", mResume );

            mStart = savedInstanceState.getInt(START_KEY);
            mCreate = savedInstanceState.getInt(CREATE_KEY);
            mResume = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESUME_KEY);
            mRestart = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESTART_KEY);


        }

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO:
        // Save state information with a collection of key-value pairs
        // 4 lines of code, one for every count variable
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        savedInstanceState.putInt(CREATE_KEY, mCreate);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESTART_KEY, mRestart);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESUME_KEY, mResume);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(START_KEY, mStart);



    }

public void displayCounts() {

        // TODO - uncomment these lines

        mTvCreate.setText("onCreate() calls: " + mCreate);
        mTvStart.setText("onStart() calls: " + mStart);
        mTvResume.setText("onResume() calls: " + mResume);
        mTvRestart.setText("onRestart() calls: " + mRestart);
```

Comment: is not your codes right?

Comment: I am student, new to android and learning it, please can you help me fixing the error that I am receiving in Eclipse at mTvCreate.setText("onCreate() calls: " + mCreate); statements.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing your OnCreate. Without it, nothing will be initialized. It seems as if you have copied this code from somewhere. Read the official documents first to get started with Android. https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

1. These are constants, this way you can use `RESTART_KEY` throughout your code without having to write out "restart" every time
2. Refer to the Docs to get a full understanding of the activity lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks, I have copied the code from activity_one.java file of assignment that I am working on and its part of onCreate() method. for question 1, resume, start, start, create variables will be generated automatically? are these activity lifecycle variables?